# Running an onClick function on Modal background clicks but not foreground clicks

Tags: javascript, css, styled-components

I am trying to add functionality to close my modal by allowing a user to click anywhere outside of the modal box to trigger a close event.  I can achieve this by using an `onClick` function on my modal background.  However since the modal is itself a child of the background this function is being run when the actual modal is clicked as well.

This is the structure with the content omitted.

```
    <ModalBackground modalDisplay={modalOpen} data-testid="modal-background" onClick={closeModal}>
      <ModalContainer
        role="dialog"
        data-testid="modal"
        modalDisplay={modalOpen}
        ref={modalRef}
        aria-labelledby={modalHeaderId}
        aria-describedby={modalBodyId}
      >
  </ModalContainer>
</ModalBackground>
```

My styles are as follows

```
const ModalContainer = styled.div`
  border: 1px solid ${basic[300]};
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 29rem;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: ${basic[100]};
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  ${(props) =>
    props.modalDisplay ? `visibility: visible;` : "visibility: hidden"}
`;

const ModalBackground = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  ${(props) =>
    props.modalDisplay ? `visibility: visible;` : "visibility: hidden"}
`;
```

I can whip up a jsfiddle if desired but I am hoping there is a straightforward solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this problem by adding this JS after the modal where I can test if the parent or child was clicked before changing the styles:

```
document.getElementById('ModalBackground').addEventListener("click", function(e) { if(e.target == this) closeModal('ModalBackground'); });
```

In you case, you would need to edit your closeModal function to have this test included.